# No Bluetooth option anywhere in Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth

I am using **`Windows 8.1 Pro`** and trying to enable bluetooth but I don't see any option to enable it. I visited:

- System Tray
- Change PC settings
- Control Panel
- services.msc

Non of these helped. I remember that I used bluetooth to share some files about a month ago in **`Windows 10`** but later I switched to Windows 8. This is really surprising behavior for me. I have included some screenshots below:

**PC settings:**

[image: No bluetooth]

**Control Panel:**

[image: No bluetooth Control panel]

**System Tray:**

[image: tray]

**Windows Search:**

[image: search]

**Device Manager:**

[image: device manager]

**services.msc:**

[image: services]
I also navigated to [this site](https://www.drivers.com/update/drivers-news/fix-bluetooth-windows-8-1/) but useless.
I tried connecting external bluetooth which worked and all the options showed up.
This is the link to my laptop softwares on official hp site: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8460p-notebook-pc/5056942 .

How do I enable my bluetooth and why is it not showing up?

Comment: If you go into Device Manager, do you see Bluetooth listed there? You can get to Device Manager by typing it into the Start menu search bar or by right-clicking This PC, clicking Manage and clicking Device Manager.

Comment: @Worthwelle I don't see it there too.

Comment: If you see an item similar to [this](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD0302U00000R0119453.png), you may need to reinstall your Bluetooth drivers. You can generally find these on the laptop manufacturer's website.

Comment: @Worthwelle There is no `Network Controller` in `Other Devices`.

Comment: Is this a desktop or laptop computer? If it's a desktop computer, you most likely do not have bluetooth hardware preinstalled.

Comment: @noumenal Its laptop.

Comment: @BlackThunder - Your problem is you are attempting to install Windows 7 drivers but you have Windows 8.1 installed.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - Only moderators can delete comments.  I am not a moderator.  If you have an issue with a comment being deleted you should bring that up with the moderator team

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently missing some drivers and the Bluetooth stack
(Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth).

Here are some sources for drivers :

[**HP Support page for the EliteBook 8460p Notebook PC**](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8460p-notebook-pc/5056942)

Enter your operating system details and have a look at the items under "Driver-Network".
Download and install the drivers for the Qualcomm Atheros QCA9000 and the
Sierra Wireless Driver. Try to install them both and reboot even if one didn't
install correctly.

[**Driver Scape HP EliteBook 8460p Drivers Download page**](https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/hp/laptops-desktops/hp-elitebook-8460p/707)

Download packages under the branch of "Bluetooth Drivers".
If two packages have the same name, use the one that is the most recent.
If you have an error message, report on it and try the next-recent version.

If this does not help, please let us know the identifier in Device Manager of the
Unknown device under Other devices. You may find that by right-click on the
Unknown device, choose Properties, click on the Details tab, in the
Property drop-down list choose Hardware IDs, right-click the displayed Value
and choose Copy. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: The `Unknown Device` says `ACPI\VEN_HPQ&DEV_0004`
`ACPI\HPQ0004`
`*HPQ0004`
`

Comment: Try this driver from the HP website : [link](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp64001-64500/sp64144.exe). If it doesn't help, there are some more drivers suggested on [this post](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/ACPI-VEN-HPQ-amp-DEV-0004-Driver-for-Windows-8-1/td-p/4537954) (use only links from HP).

Comment: From the second link in the question you have provided _(driverscape)_, I downloaded and installed _(successfully)_ [this software](https://imgur.com/gnwtc0R) but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't see anything happened. I think that I have installed incorrect software. Can you suggest me a software from there?

Comment: I would recommend installing all the driverscape drivers in the list "Bluetooth Drivers", then reboot. Only if that doesn't help, try the ones in my above comment.

Comment: A software didn't installed. I found that software's dump data. Ran a exe file. It said that `No local Bluetooth Device was detected`. Can you give me some suggestion that what should I do? I think its something about hardware.

Comment: I found the problem. I opened my laptop cover and saw that there is a device on which was written `Broadcom`. Its wire was broken and also not connected. Now I don't know where can I get new wire from. Look at the wire and the device : [broadcom-Bcm.....](https://www.adverts.ie/laptop-parts-and-accessories/broadcom-bcm92045nmd-bluetooth-2-0-module/6884210)

Comment: I was also starting to think that you had a hardware problem, since you had all the drivers you needed. A repairman might be able to re-attach the wire, or to replace the card.

Comment: The problem is with the wire. I reattached the wire but it was broken. _+1 for great suggestions_

Comment: The wires inside that wire are very thin and covered with strong plastic. I can't even rejoin them by myself. I don't think that any repairman will have a spare wire like that.

Comment: Another possibility is to just ignore the broken card and get an external wireless adapter connected via USB. An external adapter is very cheap and might be the simplest solution (a repairman will cost more).

Comment: You are not understanding. The wire is connected to the card which can be unplugged from the card. The card is perfect. I just need a wire to connect the card.

Comment: If you can find a serial number on the cable, you can search for it and buy it online or in a shop. Otherwise, buying another whole card with the cable is also very cheap. An example is [here on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/BROADCOM-BCM92045NMD-T60H928-WIRELESS-BLUETOOTH-ADAPTER-CARD-FOR-DELL-GATEWAY-HP/391181021221?epid=2249254534&hash=item5b1434b025:g:2PQAAOSwTmtaAMCS) for $3.95 + delivery. Or just take it with you to a shop and show it - they might have something compatible.

Comment: Yeah found this one: https://www.ebay.com/itm/BLUETOOTH-CABLE-HP-ELITEBOOK-8740W-6017B0230801-BCM92070MD-ORIGINAL/283061641340?hash=item41e7c9e07c:g:MqQAAOSw4apbTpQI But its to expensive. Here is a clear image: https://www.pollin.de/images/600x600x90/I722335.1-Bluetooth-Modul-BROADCOM-QCOM-BCM92070MD-QBT410UB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

So I've looked on HP's site for a Bluetooth driver. Your laptop likely was previously using the Windows 7-compatible Bluetooth driver on Windows 10.

Here is a [link](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8460p-notebook-pc/5056942#ob-119298-1) which places you at the right place on the page. It is at the top. Download and install the driver, and you should be able to use Bluetooth devices with ease. Just because this driver is not listed in the 8.1 support does not mean that it won't work. It simply means that they have not tested it.

I would like to add however, that Windows 8.1 is slowly approaching its' end of life and I recommend switching back to Windows 10.

Here is a more direct link to [download.](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp61501-62000/sp61616.exe)

Edit: Since you're receiving compatibility errors, try this [link](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp52501-53000/sp52717.exe)

Comment: The link you have provided me redirects me to same link I have provided. You will have to find a more precise url.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. My laptop don't supports Windows 10. Almost all drivers don't work. So I switched back to Windows 8.

Comment: @BlackThunder Well just select Windows 7, 64 bit as OS and download the win7 version

Comment: I've updated my answer with the direct download.

Comment: It says `Compatibility issues`. I also tried running it in compatibility mode. 
Here is a link to image: https://imgur.com/6UT9iMk

Comment: @BlackThunder - What do you mean it doesn't support Windows 10?  You were running Windows 10 on the device until you switched to Windows 8.1.  You shouldn't be getting Compatability Issues between Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, which means, the driver actually is likely not designed to support neither.

Comment: @BlackThunder I've added another piece of software that may work

Comment: The second software also says the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Bluetooth drivers on your computer. I use this site [softwaretested.com/drivers/bluetooth/](https://softwaretested.com/drivers/bluetooth/), but you can find a specific driver specifically for your Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it.

1. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools.
2. Click on Computer Management. Select the Device Manager Option on left of the screen.
3. Click on the arrow next to Bluetooth. You will see adapter name.( In my case - Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 adapter.
4. Right-click on the adapter and select Disable. Go to desktop and refresh (f5).
5. Again Right-click on adapter and select Enable option.
   This fixed my Bluetooth problem and hopefully yours too!

Answer (score -1):

The HP Support site you linked to states that laptop uses the Qualcomm Atheros QCA9000 WiFi chip set and some of the chip sets in this family have the WiFi and Bluetooth on in the same hardware.

Try installing the wireless LAN driver from that site. Windows may currently be using a default driver that does not support the advanced features (like Bluetooth) of that chip set.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same symptoms before and finally (after going through most of the above suggested steps) realised that my bluetooth adapter was not plugged in fully (at the back of my PC)!!!

I realise you have a laptop and I assume the bluetooth is internal? However do you have a hardware switch on the laptop body which could be set to off? Or perhaps one of the function keys for flight mode switched on? Always worth checking :P

Comment: This would not explain the fact that the device driver is nowhere to be seen on the device.